# How to capitalize each word of a NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am trying to figure out how to take a given NSString and convert it to camel case.  I have seen lots of code samples out there for going back and forth between underscores_ and camel-case, but I am dealing with strings that are capitalized.

So if I had the string:  `12345 SAMPLE STREET #12` or `789 N HASKELL STREET`, how would I be able to convert those to `12345 Sample Street #12` and `789 N Haskell Street`?

Sorry if it's a stupid question, but I'm pretty new to the objective-c / cocoa frameworks world.

Comment: That's title case/proper noun caps, not camel case.

Comment: CamelCase would be 12345SampleStreetNumber12 or 789NorthHaskellStreet.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[`-[NSString capitalizedString]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-capitalizedString)

Comment: Probably best useful&short answer on SO :)

Comment: Dot notation simplicity: NSString *lowerCaseString = @"lower case words"; NSString *stringName = lowerCaseString.capitalizedString;